# Bootstrap label and input filed not displaying horizontal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have copied and pasted the sample code from bootstrap. I have included bootstrap CSS and JS file & jQuery library. [Base CSS - Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms)

For some reason labels and input fields are showing inline. Can someone take a look what I am doing wrong?

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
              </label>
              <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
            </div>
          </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Your `form` tag looks fine, I believe you forgot to add 
`container` `div` class & `<!DOCTYPE html>` HTML5

Comment: Put your code on jsfiddle.

Comment: You tagged the question Bootstrap 3, but you are linking to the Bootstrap 2 docs, and the code you have is also Bootstrap 2. If you have the above code hooked to Bootstrap 3 CSS, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .form-group instead of .control-group class.

*Remember to set a container with .col-*-* classes after the form tag.

Ex.

```
 <form class="" role="form" method="POST" action="{form_action}" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">      
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label label-fw">Vendida?&ensp;</label>
           {chk_sold}
        </div><!-- form group -->

        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="txt_title" class="control-label label-fw">T&iacute;tulo&ensp;</label>
           <input name="txt_title" type="text" class="form-control input" id="txt_title" value="{txt_title}" placeholder="titulo del producto">
        </div><!-- form group -->

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txt_title" class="control-label label-fw">Categor&iacute;a&ensp;</label>
           {cbo_type}
        </div><!-- form group -->

        <div class="">
           <label for="txt_aution_date_d" class="control-label label-fw">Fecha&ensp;</label>
           <input name="txt_auction_date_d" type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_auction_date_d" value="{txt_auction_date_d}" placeholder="MM/DD/AAAA">
        </div><!-- form group -->                       

     </div><!-- col-sm-6 col-md-6 -->
  </form>
```

Let me know if that worked.